# Building Flex charts with an ant task

Tags: apache-flex, ant, licensing

Using the Flex ant task to build our application results in the "Flex Data Visualization Trial" watermark being displayed in our charts.

We have professional licenses for flex builder but do not know how to tell the ant task about these.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=configuring_environment_2.html#212596  .
It has several options, but none explicetely for an ant task.

However, I tried this in ant with the latest version of flex, and it worked (flex 3.X):

```
<mxmlc ...>
...
<license product="flexbuilder3" serial-number="000000000000"/>
....
</mxmlc>
```

Comment: should the serial number have "-" or no "-" between numbers?